# Public DNS not resolving with Amazon EC2 Micro

Tags: amazon-ec2

So for some reason I cannot access my Amazon EC2 server through a web browser, or ping. But, I can SSH into it with the Public DNS address given to me.

I used Nmap on it, and following are the results.

```
Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-02-13 18:00 Central Standard Time    
NSE: Loaded 57 scripts for scanning.    
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.    
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.    
Initiating NSE at 18:00    
Completed NSE at 18:00, 0.00s elapsed    
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.    
Initiating Ping Scan at 18:00    
Scanning ec2-50-16-96-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com (50.16.96.100) [4 ports]    
Completed Ping Scan at 18:00, 2.75s elapsed (1 total hosts)    
Nmap scan report for ec2-50-16-96-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com (50.16.96.100) [host down]    
NSE: Script Post-scanning.    
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.    
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.    
Read data files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap    
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 6.71 seconds    
           Raw packets sent: 8 (304B) | Rcvd: 2 (80B)
```

How can I view my server's web host through a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a port scan on your IP(50.16.96.100) SSH is the only port responding are you sure you have a webserver running , if your sure you have Apache installed then run

> service httpd start

to see if it is offline.

Comment: It is online and enabled. Do you know how to open up ports from Amazon EC2?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: OK, can you select my answer as accepted to close the question and et it out of unanswered please.